# Javascript Function not executing/returning value

Tags: javascript

I have a function and I want to see what the value of index is.  It gives me 0 however.  I thought that was wierd so I put a console.log in function() to see if it was executing or not and I didn't recieve an output which tells me that function() isn't getting called.  Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

```
function jsTest() {

    var index = 0;
    var counter = 0;
    var obj = {};
    obj.index = index; //obj.index = 0 at this point

    var func = function () {

        for (index = 0; index < 10; index++) {
            counter += 2;
            console.log(counter); //Doesn't execute for some reason
        }
        obj.index++;
    };

    obj.func = func; //executes function()
    this.index++;
    return index;
}

var x = jsTest();
console.log(x);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
obj.func = func;
```

doesn't actually call func, it assigns the property `func` for `obj` to be the function `func`. If you want to call `func`, you should add parentheses afterwards, like

```
obj.func = func();
```

Comment: Gotcha, so would it be safe to assume that from this that "return index" is returning a value of 0 since function() isn't being called

Comment: The function certainly isn't being called, and that would prevent index from being incremented. You've got a couple of different indexes floating around, though, so if this doesn't fix your problem I'd make sure you're returning and incrementing the right one